# Read a file and get an array of strings

Tags: rust, idioms

I want to read a file and get back a vector of `String`s. The following function works, but is there a more concise or idiomatic way?

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn lines_from_file(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut file = match File::open(filename) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(_) => panic!("no such file"),
    };
    let mut file_contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut file_contents)
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read!");
    let lines: Vec<String> = file_contents.split("\n")
        .map(|s: &str| s.to_string())
        .collect();
    lines
}
```

Some things that seem suboptimal to me:

- Two separate error checks for reading the file.
- Reading the entire file to a `String`, which will be thrown away. This would be particularly wasteful if I only wanted the first N lines.
- Making a `&str` per line, which will be thrown away, instead of somehow going straight from the file to a `String` per line.

How can this be improved?

Comment: Use the `lines()` iterator: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted. If it's considered too subjective, I propose that the `idiomatic` tag be removed, since it exactly describes the kind of thing I'm asking about.

Answer (score 39):

[DK.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801708/155423) is quite right and has great explanation. However, you stated:

> Read a file and get an array of strings

Rust arrays have a fixed length, known at compile time, so I assume you really mean "vector". I would write it like this:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    path::Path,
};

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Vec<String> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);
    buf.lines()
        .map(|l| l.expect("Could not parse line"))
        .collect()
}

// ---

fn main() {
    let lines = lines_from_file("/etc/hosts");
    for line in lines {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}
```

1. As in the other answer, it's worth it to use a generic type that implements `AsRef` for the filename.
2. [`Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) shortens the panic on `Err`.
3. [`BufRead::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) handles multiple types of newlines, not just `"\n"`.
4. `BufRead::lines` also gives you separately allocated `String`s, instead of one big glob.
5. There's no reason to collect to a temporary variable just to return it. There's especially no reason to repeat the type (`Vec<String>`).

If you wanted to return a `Result` on failure, you can squash the implementation down to one line if you want:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, BufRead, BufReader},
    path::Path,
};

fn lines_from_file(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> io::Result<Vec<String>> {
    BufReader::new(File::open(filename)?).lines().collect()
}

// ---

fn main() {
    let lines = lines_from_file("/etc/hosts").expect("Could not load lines");
    for line in lines {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 'down to one line' function seems to return the entire text as 1 line for me, your first worked.

Comment: @Blankman I think the issue is that you aren't handling the returned `Result` from `lines_from_file`. `Option` and `Result` implement `IntoIterator`, so that might be tricking you.

Answer (score 22):

As [BurntSushi said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801031/read-a-file-and-get-an-array-of-strings#comment49651189_30801031), you *could* just use [the `lines()` iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines).  But, to address your question as-is:

- You should probably read [Error Handling in Rust](http://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/); those `unwrap()`s should be turned into `?`s, with the function's result becoming a `Result<Vec<String>, E>` for some reasonable `E`. Here, we reuse the `io::Result` type alias.
- Use the `lines()` iterator.  The other thing you can do is read the whole file into a `String` *and return that*; there's [a `lines()` iterator for strings as well](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines).
- This one you can't do anything about: `file_contents` owns its contents, and you can't split them up into multiple, owned `String`s.  The only thing you can do is borrow the contents of each line, then convert that into a new `String`.  That said, the way you've put this implies that you believe creating a `&str` is expensive; it isn't.  It's *literally* just computing a pair of offsets and returning those.  A `&str` slice is effectively equivalent to `(*const u8, usize)`.

Here's a modified version which does basically the same thing:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::path::Path;

fn lines_from_file<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

One other change I made: `filename` is now a generic `P: AsRef<Path>`, because that's what [`File::open`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) wants, so it will accept more types without needing conversion.

Comment: Neat! But doesn't returning a Result imply that if the file is unreadable, it will be the caller's problem? Maybe there's no way to avoid that while also being lazy about reading the file?

Comment: @NathanLong Using `unwrap` or `panic!` means that if the file is unreadable, the entire thread explodes and the caller dies without warning.  If the caller doesn't care about this, they can just call `unwrap` on the result and get the same explody behaviour.  *Or* they can actually decide what to do with the error.  Either way, it has no impact on reading the file: both will cause the function to stop executing in one fashion or another.

Comment: Can you add an example of invocation of `lines_from_file`?